# Angular routing with segment wildcard

Tags: angular

I am setting up routing for an Angular 6 app, and I want to have a route which can match a variable number of segments. Currently I have a route config that looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/catalog', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
  { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent, canActivate: [SessionGuard] },
  { path: 'repo/:name', component: RepositoryComponent, canActivate: [SessionGuard] }
];
```

That matches a url like `repo/test` and sends it to the `RepositoryComponent`, but `repo/foo/bar` raises an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'repo/foo/bar'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'repo/foo/bar'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1341)
```

I am used to the convention in ASP.NET MVC which allows me to declare a route like this:

```
[HttpGet("repo/{*name}")]
```

Which would match both `repo/test` and `repo/foo/bar` and place everything after the first slash (`test` or `foo/bar`) in a `name` argument. Is there a way to get equivalent behavior with Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is no built-in way to do this. What I've ended up with is a routing setup like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/catalog', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
  { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent, canActivate: [SessionGuard] },
  { path: 'repo', component: RepositoryComponent, canActivate: [SessionGuard], children: [{
    path: '**', component: RepositoryComponent
  }] }
];
```

That handles the request routing, but not the parameter evaluation. To get the segments matched by the `**` wildcard, I need to scrounge around in the injected `Router` object on my `RepositoryComponent`:

```
getRepo(): void {
  this.Name = this.route.snapshot.children[0].url.join('/');
}
```